# Javascript: Need help validating two aspects of a form, which will then enable the SUBMIT button

Tags: javascript, validation, function

My name is Romano and I'm looking for some guidance on a form validation process.
I currently have a registration form that has a validation process against the **USERNAME** field and a **TERMS and CONDITIONS** checkbox.

The validation I have against the checkbox is easy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function apply()
 {
document.frm.sub.disabled=true;
if(document.frm.chk.checked==true)
{
document.frm.sub.disabled=false;
}
if(document.frm.chk.checked==false)
{
document.frm.sub.enabled=false;
}
}
</script>
```

and the form field calls the function:

This works fine.

I also have another block of javascript code that validates the username so that it meets minimum requirements AND ALSO ensures that it currently does not exist in my database.  That block of code is much larger, and looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#username").change(function() 
{ 
var username = $("#username").val();
if(username.length > 5)//if the lenght greater than 5 characters
{
$("#availability_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

 $.ajax({  //Make the Ajax Request
 type: "POST",  
 url: "ajax_check_username.php",  
 data: "username="+ username, 
 success: function(server_response){  

 $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

if(server_response == '0')
{ 
$("#availability_status").html('<img src="images/available.png" align="absmiddle">
  <font color="Green">Available </font>  ')
}  
else  if(server_response == '1')
{  
 $("#availability_status").html('<img src="images/not_available.png" align="absmiddle">
    <font color="red">Not Available </font>') 
 }  
     });
  } 

  }); 

  }
   else
   {

   $("#availability_status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Username too short</font>');
  }
  return false;
  });

   });
  </script>
```

And this code works perfectly too.

What I'd like to have done is to integrate both blocks of code so that the SUBMIT button is enabled ONLY when all conditions are true.  in other words, when the checkbox is checked AND the username is greather than 5 characters AND it does not exist in the database.

So, is this an easy task?  Sounds like it should be but I'm at a loss (probably from looking at code for the past two days).

Thanks!!!

Comment: Well for a start your `apply()` function can be reduced to one line of code as follows: `document.frm.sub.disabled = !document.frm.chk.checked;`. Also you don't need to call `.ajaxComplete()` from inside your Ajax `success` handler.

Comment: As you can tell from your code you have some syntax errors. See all that red text? That should be your first clue that something is wrong.

Comment: @nnnnnn:  Thanks!  I love less code.

Comment: @elcanrs: That's probably due to a quick copy/paste error and editing I did before submitting the question.  The code works fine.  The question I had is how can I integrate both blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

You want the validation triggered change of either the checkbox or the name. Given that you're doing an Ajax check to see if the username is valid I'd set a flag to indicate whether the current name is valid so that the Ajax runs only when the name changes and not the checkbox. So perhaps something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var usernameOK = false,   // I assume username starts out blank
        termsChecked = false;

    function setSubmitEnabling() {
        document.frm.sub.disabled = !(usernameOK && termsChecked);
    }


    $("#yourCBidHere").click(function() {
        termsChecked = this.checked;
        setSubmitEnabling();
    });

    $("#username").change(function() {
        var username = this.value;
        if(username.length <= 5) { //if the name too short
            $("#availability_status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Username too short</font>');
            usernameOK = false;
            setSubmitEnabling();
            return;
        }
        $("#availability_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
        usernameOK = false;
        setSubmitEnabling();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "ajax_check_username.php",  
            data: "username="+ username, 
            success: function(server_response){
                if(server_response == '0'){ 
                    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="images/available.png" align="absmiddle"><font color="Green">Available </font>');
                    usernameOK = true;
                } else if(server_response == '1') {  
                    $("#availability_status").html('<img src="images/not_available.png" align="absmiddle"><font color="red">Not Available </font>');
                    usernameOK = false;
                }
                setSubmitEnabling();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow.  Amazing!!  I tried your code.  At first it didn't work but everything looked right so I looked at it a little more closely - step by step - and noticed that the 3rd to the last and 4th to the last semi-colon needed to be removed.  Strange, but that did it.  Those semi-colons do it to me all the time. THANKS AGAIN!!!

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited my answer to remove the 4th last semi-colon, the one that was after the closing `}` on the success function, but you shouldn't need to remove the 3rd last one.